# Запись на внешний накопитель в Android

Tags: java, android, android-permissions

Для записи на внешние (съёмные) накопители обычно получают доступ к корню накопителя через провайдера документов. Но в некоторых приложениях используется такой вот диалог [image: сам диалог]

Как это реализовано?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting?

Comment: Запись на съёмный накопитель интересует. Именно запись и именно на съёмный.

Comment: Вам же дали ссылку на нужную информацию! Кастомизируйте стандартный диалог и вписывайте  туду  что угодно.  Выберите нужную константу из https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission  Если память не изменяет то это "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE".

Comment: Решён вопрос, всем спасибо. Решение: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54945401/android-ask-write-to-sd-card-permission-dialog

Answer (score 1):

Это реализует API Storage Access Framework, внедренный в  21 API level - https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html#client

Comment: Ну да, это уже ближе к делу. Я в курсе про SAF, про получение и удержание прав. Меня конкретно диалог этот интересует, как его получить то? Вместо открытия провайдера и выбора корня накопителя.